# Generating random code that is writing over memory in terminal

Tags: java

DISCLAIMER: I know that the linked code is extremely poorly written, optimized, and documented, but I was just messing around for fun and had absolutely no intentions on posting it until I realized what it looked like it was doing.

In the screenshot, you will see a copy of the code that I was running (also copied below) as well as some outputs I got - the reason why I am posting this.  In the below code, I did not realize before, but it seems to have written over the '@' and '~' in my working directory (this happened when the output was output to terminal and not written to the document as shown in that specific command).  In further testing, I ended up getting it to write a bunch of gibberish to my input buffer(?) which is shown in the second terminal window (it seems to be more of a visual glitch than text written to my input buffer as I am able to write directly over it and pressing enter treats it as a blank line).

Any thoughts?

```
//Prints out a bunch of random characters converted from binary (because why not)
//Originally intended just to convert binary to ASCII text but I got bored...
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = "";
//creates a bunch of random binary and writes it to input
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
                    input += (int)(Math.random()*2);
                }
                input += " ";
            }
//splits binary into 8 bit chunks
        String[] eightBit = input.split(" ");

//binary -> int
        for(String i : eightBit){
            if(i.length() == 8){
                int value = 0;
                String[] oneBit = i.split("");
                for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
                    if(oneBit[k].equals("1")){
                        switch(k){
                            case 0:
                                value+=128;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                value+=64;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                value+=32;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                value+=16;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                value+=8;
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                value+=4;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                value+=2;
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                value+=1;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //int -> char
                System.out.print((char)value);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output of my own testing here:

[image: 1]

EDIT: Yes.  This is just a complicated noise generator that I didn't simplify before posting.  My question is why does generating random noise cause writing to memory used in terminal / input buffer.  A simplified version of the noise generator is below (and it has the same percieved effects as the binary -> noise version).

```
public class TestSimp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            System.out.print((char)((int)(Math.random()*256)));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: I continued testing and got [this output](https://pastebin.com/vAv9S4vW) when searching for what was written to the input buffer.  It seems to be nowhere else in the randomly generated noise which seems odd.

Here's the code I used to generate that output (I had to press enter to try a few times until I got the linked output):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestSimp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputBuffer = "";
        do{
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                System.out.print((char)((int)(Math.random()*256)));
            }
            System.out.println();
            inputBuffer = in.nextLine();
        } while(inputBuffer.equals(""));
        System.out.println("--- INPUT BUFFER ---");
        System.out.println(inputBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're printing random noise on the standard output. Some of that noise is bound to be control characters that will mess with your terminal.

Comment: Why were Strings needed in your code? `value` appears to just be a random integer between 0 and 255. There's a lot of unnecessary conversions and String splits that I'm not sure are adding anything.

Comment: @codebod as is mentioned both as a comment and in the header of this post, this was just me messing around.  The initial project was solely to convert binary -> integer -> ascii char, but I got bored of doing that which is why I created a randomizer, but yes, the edit in the OP should clerify.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I would assume that is the reason as well, I am curious as to what ASCII characters / combinations allow random output in terminal to write to memory locations used in other places / input buffer during runtime.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that anything is "writing to memory locations used in other places". All I see is the result of sending random data (which will include random control-codes) to a terminal. You'd get similar corruption if you started `cat`ing random binaries.

Comment: @TripeHound This makes a lot of sense; I didn't know that, but I am still unclear as to what writes to the input buffer after the program is terminated.  I would suspect control codes executed during runtime would not have such an effect post execution unless it is some form of latency.